# When creating a csv from a custom controller, the resulting csv is skipping lines. How do I prevent this?

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to make a visualforce page where people can download a csv of a small custom Controller. The resulting csv is placing a blank line between records. Is there a fix for this?

```
<apex:page cache="true"  controller="members168" 
    contentType="application/octet-stream#MemberDirectory.csv" 
    showHeader="false" sidebar="false" language="en-US">
    "Salutation","First Name","Last Name","State","Title","Email","Phone","Region"
    <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="item">
        "{!item.Salutation}","{!item.firstname}","{item.lastname}","{!item.State_Represented__c}","{!item.Title}","{!item.email}","{!item.mobilephone}","{!item.Region__c}"
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Tried the code and it did not add any blank lines between records. Could you elaborate more on the problem?

Comment: I would wager that this has to do with the newline convention in the output data and the viewing computer. Windows CRLF newlines can appear doubled (blank lines) in software expecting LF only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that adding the extra line break in apex:repeat is causing the extra lines. You need to lose one of them.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="item">"{!item.Salutation}","{!item.firstname}","{item.lastname}","{!item.State_Represented__c}","{!item.Title}","{!item.email}","{!item.mobilephone}","{!item.Region__c}"
</apex:repeat>
```

In this particular case, the line breaks in your source code are critically important. If you have extra line breaks, they'll appear in your CSV file.